# "Can't merge because of conflicts: [Cannot update enabled setting for [_source], Cannot update excludes setting for [_source]]"

Tags: elasticsearch

How to finish this at elasticsearch?

```
Can't merge because of conflicts:
[Cannot update enabled setting for [_source],
Cannot update excludes setting for [_source]]
```

I write this:

```
PUT /my_index/_mapping/article {  
    "article": {    
        "_source": {      
            "excludes": [ "date"]     
        }    
    }  }
```

but the result is:

```
{    "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Can't merge because of conflicts: [Cannot update enabled setting for [_source], Cannot update excludes setting
for [_source]]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Can't merge because of conflicts: [Cannot update enabled setting for [_source], Cannot update excludes setting for
[_source]]"    },    "status": 400 }
```

Comment: Looks like you `_source` is disabled. Enable it and try again. [Read more](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15997)

Comment: @PolynomialProton but it seems that we cannot re enable the index again if it already exists,  after the index _source is disabled. I can't find the solution. Can you have give some hints to enable it?

Comment: @carton.swing you could reindex the documents to apply changes.

Comment: @PolynomialProton.  according to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html , if I disabled _source, I couldn't use reindex feature.

Comment: @carton.swing I cant think of another way but to reprocess i.e. index from the source/db to a new index and use alias to point to new index.